# Calculate distance of closest point using latitude/longitude en masse?

Tags: c#, sql, google-maps, geolocation

I'm trying to figure out, on a theoretical basis, how to find the closest points to a single point. All of these points (75,000+ points) are mapped out with latitude and longitude. The Haversine formula for distance is what I'm using to find the distance between two points, but does this formula scale on the fly?

I'm using a web front end + SQL Server backend. I can't even begin to imagine how to do this... find all distances on the fly then sort them based on distance? Again, I'm wondering if this scales to as many points as I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/) goes into detail about this exact subject.

The main optimization is using an index on lat/long. If you know that there must be a point within some distance of your query, you can use that known distance to only check points within that box. Because of the index, the database does a range scan.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe such a niche article exists. Great link. Didn't realize indexing is key.

Comment: I don't think it's really niche--think of all the mobile apps that use your current location to find things. (Also, ha, "indexing is key." :) )

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have lat and long in an SQL database.

The best you can do with a problem like this is just to find all distances and sort them by value.

SELECT (haversine formula) as distance
FROM table
ORDER BY distance ASC

Comment: Yes, all lat/long are in a database. I haven't implemented a solution yet, but I'm thinking that Haversine formula X 75000 would be a long query to execute, hence my problem. It looks pretty math heavy. Your opinions?

Comment: Haversine formula is not too math heavy. Most computers use lookup tables to calculate sine and cosine, so it's a pretty quick calculation.  75000 rows really isn't all that many. Even at 128 bytes per row (a lot for two numbers), that's only 10MB of data. It will only take a few seconds, maybe a minute or two with the sort.